# How to Use a Single ImageProxy in Multiple Analysis Functions in Android CameraX API?

Tags: android, mediapipe

I am using the Android CameraX API to build an application that performs both pose and hand landmark detection. In my pipeline, I have two different functions, detectPose and detectHand, which are supposed to operate on the same frame received from the camera.

Here's a simplified code snippet for setting up the image analyzer:
`imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3) .setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation) .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST) .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) .build() .also { it.setAnalyzer(backgroundExecutor) { image -> detectPose(image) detectHand(image) } }`

Each function (detectPose and detectHand) tries to use the`ImageProxy` to perform its own analysis, but it seems that ImageProxy is automatically closed after it is used once.

I tried bypassing the `.use` function to prevent `ImageProxy` from closing, but then I encountered a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels error.`

Is there a way to use a single ImageProxy in multiple analysis functions without running into these issues? If not, what are the alternative solutions?

What did you try?
I attempted to bypass the `.use` extension function to prevent the ImageProxy from being automatically closed. What did you try?
I attempted to prevent ImageProxy from automatically closing via the `.use` extension function. Specifically, I commented out the `imageProxy.use { ... }` line within both the detectPose and detectHand functions and moved its contents outside of the `.use` block.

What were you expecting?
I was expecting both my detectPose and detectHand functions to successfully perform their respective analyses on the single frame represented by the ImageProxy. I wanted both functions to operate on the same ImageProxy object without causing it to close prematurely.

However, upon doing this, I ran into a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels error`, which prevented my functions from executing as expected.